# Run program when window user switches active window

Tags: windows, winapi, hook, autohotkey, kiosk-mode

I would like to prevent user from switching window (similarly to kiosk  applications). However I would like to turn this behaviour od (and off) anytime by keyboard shortcut with for any application.

The best thing I achieved was a AutoHotkey script which waits for activating keyboard shortcut and which detects changes of active window and when the active window is changed it runs a program (Clearlock in my case) however locking the computer would be also fine for me.

I use this when I do something with someone on my computer and when I want to leave temporarily and not lock the computer completely. That could my friends, girlfriend or coworkers understand as me not trusting them.

Here is the autohotkey script I have:

```
Gui +LastFound 
hWnd := WinExist()
DllCall( "RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt,Hwnd )
MsgNum := DllCall( "RegisterWindowMessage", Str,"SHELLHOOK" )
OnMessage( MsgNum, "ShellMessage" )
Return

ShellMessage( wParam,lParam )
{
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %lParam%
    If (wParam=4) { ;HSHELL_WINDOWACTIVATED
        global kiosk
        If (kiosk) {
            global kiosk
            kiosk := 0

            Run "%PORTABLE_APPS%\utility\clearlock\ClearLock.exe"
        }
    }
}

kiosk := 0

^!K::
    global kiosk
    global kiosk
    If (kiosk) {
        kiosk := 0
        ToolTip "unlocked`n%kiosk%"
    } Else {
        kiosk := 1
        ToolTip "The screen will be locked if necessary`n%kiosk%"
    }
    sleep 1000
    ToolTip
    Return
```

The script works flawlessly on Windows 7. However it doesn't do anything on windows 10.

What could cause the problem? How do I solve it?
I would like either to correct the script.
Or any other solution how to invisibly lock the computer or swich aplication any application to kios mode or to prevent switching applications.

However I don't need it to super secure. Because I wan't the people I want to prevent from doing anything nasty are friends.

Comment: Why don't you do a proper kiosk

Comment: Try running it as administrator.

Comment: David Heffernan: Proper kiosk is for different use case. I imagine that I work normally on whatever I am dooing and then when I want to leave the computer temporaritly, I invisibly lock the computer without others noticing that the computer is locked.

Answer (score 1):

If the utmost security isn't a focus, then the simplest solution would be something like this:

```
F3::
Loop
{
WinActivate, Untitled - Notepad
Sleep, 50
if getkeystate("Esc", "p")
    {        
        break
    }
}
return
```